# Finding the location of a row for csv files in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have the below code written using the pandas library:

```
# function : check for time
def checktime(reportedtime, scheduledtimestart, scheduledtimeend):
    if scheduledtimestart <= reportedtime <= scheduledtimeend:
        return "Yes"
    else:
        return "No"

df.loc[sub_df.index, 'Access Valid'] = checktime(time_date, schedule_start_date, schedule_end_date)

df.to_excel(current_directory + '/files/updated_report.xlsx', index=False)
```

`df` is the main/original dataframe. While `sub_df` is the modified/filtered dataframe. `Access Valid` is the column im trying to append values to.

The program checks if the time at which a request made by the user `time_date` is within their `schedule_start_date` and `schedule_end_date`. then it would update the cell under the column `Access Valid` to either `yes` or `no`.

## Question

I have been requested to modify my code and use `import csv` library rather than `import pandas` due to size, however im not able to determine the **location** of the specified row in order to append the `Access Valid` to the csv file and export it as an excel file.

Users list:

```
user; scheduled start date; scheduled end date;
test1; 2022-09-01 00:00:00; 2022-09-30 23:59:59;
test2; 2022-09-01 00:00:00; 2022-09-14 23:59:59;
```

Sample file structure (file contains over 1000+ requests):

```
time; user; Access Valid
2022-09-20 09:09:00; test1; 
2022-09-21 05:00:00; test2;
```

Desired file output:

```
time; user; Access Valid
2022-09-20 09:09:00; test1; yes
2022-09-21 05:00:00; test2; no
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `csv` the code would be as follows:

```
import csv

with open(FILE_WITH_ACCESS_DATA) as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            #header
            print(f'{";".join(row)}')
        else:
            #content
            print(f'{row[0]};{row[1]}; ' + checktime(time_date, schedule_start_date, schedule_end_date))
        line_count += 1
```

Comment: You want to put `line_count += 1` outside the `if`, or just use `enumerate` in the `for` loop.